# How can I create a `with-eval-after-load-all` in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: macros, elisp

I'm trying to create something similar to `with-eval-after-load` except that the body evaluates after all features have been provided. Additionally, the feature list must be provided at runtime.

For example, I want something like

```
(setq feature-list '(a b))
(something feature-list (message "a and b both provided"))
```

where this performs functionality equivalent to

```
(with-eval-after-load 'a
  (with-eval-after-load 'b
    (message "a and b both provided")))
```

Providing the list at runtime seems to be the tricky part. Without that requirement I could write a macro:

```
(defmacro eval-after-load-all (features body)
  (if (null features)
      body
    `(with-eval-after-load (quote ,(car features))
       (eval-after-load-all ,(cdr features) ,body))))
```

and pass the list with:

```
(eval-after-load-all (a b) (message "a and b both provided"))
```

But passing it `feature-list` will cause it to use the literal characters "feature-list".

I've tried defining a recursive function:

```
(defun eval-after-load-all (features body)
  (if (null features)
      body
    (with-eval-after-load (car features)
      (eval-after-load-all (cdr features) body))))
```

But when I evaluate

```
(eval-after-load-all feature-list (message "a and b both provided"))
(provide 'a)
;; (provide 'b)
```

It triggers an error at the `(provide 'a)` call complaining about `void-variable body` in the recursive call step (i.e. last expression in the function). This scope confuses me. Why is `body` void here?

I also tried to wrap the macro in a function so that I could pass it the evaluated arguments:

```
(defun macro-wrapper (features body)
  (eval-after-load-all features body))
```

but this complains at function definition that `features` is not a list: `wrong-type-argument listp features`.

Comment: Have a look at the function `eval-after-load` - it might be easier to use at runtime than the macro.

Comment: Maybe your problem could be solved by providing a module "my-module" that *requires* both A and B (or loops over a list and require them all)? This way you only need `(with-eval-after-load 'my-module ...)`?

Comment: Unfortunately my use case is somewhat the inverse of that. A and B may not have been provided yet in which case require would signal an error.

Comment: I'm currently using with-eval-after-load for each feature and guarding the code with a predicate. This sort of works but in addition to needing to know whether all features are provided, the predicate also needs to know whether the other eval-after-loads have executed their code and not execute if so. Another feature is provided once the guarded code has executed so maybe I can test that, but this is starting to feel like a race condition (or at least I'm not sure how emacs handles this sort of thing).

Comment: The race condition being, does the guarded code finish executing before or after the other with-eval-after-loads get invoked.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may not use the symbol `features` as an argument since that is (I cite the doc of `features`):

   > A list of symbols which are the features of the executing Emacs.
   >   Used by `featurep` and `require`, and altered by `provide`.
2. The following code for `eval-after-load-all` works as expected. It is derived from your recursive function definition.
   I added the evaluation of the form as function or as expression with `funcall` or `eval`, respectively, I used the backquote for the lambda, and I introduced the quoting for the list and the expression in the generated lambda expression.

```el
(defun eval-after-load-all (my-features form)
  "Run FORM after all MY-FEATURES are loaded.
See `eval-after-load' for the possible formats of FORM."
  (if (null my-features)
      (if (functionp form)
      (funcall form)
    (eval form))
    (eval-after-load (car my-features)
      `(lambda ()
     (eval-after-load-all
      (quote ,(cdr my-features))
      (quote ,form))))))
```